# Implementing softmax regression

Tags: python, neural-network, softmax

I am trying to make a neural network using softmax regression. I am using the following regression formula:

[image]

Lets say I have an input of 1000x100. In other words, lets say I have 1000 images each of dimensions 10x10. Now, let's say the images are images of letters from A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J and I'm trying to predict this. My design is the following: to have 100 inputs (each image) and 10 outputs.

I have the following doubts. Given that n is superscript in x^n, with regards to the numerator, should I perform the dot product of w (w = weights whose dimensions are 10x100 - 10 representing the number of outputs and 100 representing the number of inputs) and a single x(a single image) or all the imagines combined(1000x100)? I am coding in python and so if I do dot product of w and x^T (10x100 dot 100x1000), then I am not sure how I can make that an exponent. I am using numpy. I am having a hard time wrapping my mind around these matrices on how they can be raised as an exponent.

Comment: 1) x^n represents the output of all nodes from the previous layer; it is not an exponent. w_i represents the weight vector of the node i in the softmax layer. 2) Dot product will always be performed with 2 same sized vectors. [Here is my implementation](https://github.com/supersaiyanmode/Image-Orientation-Detector/blob/master/orient.py#L52) from some time back if you'd want to take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are training Neural Networks, it might we worth while to check [Theano](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/mlp.html) library. It features various output thresholding functions like *tanh*, *softmax*, etc. and allows training of neural networks on GPU.

Also x^n is the output of the last layer in the above formula, not input raised to some exponent. You can't put matrix in exponent.

You should check more about softmax regression. [This](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/supervised/SoftmaxRegression/) might be of help.